# Debugging speech recognition of custom word PocketSphinx.js

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

QUESTION: I am looking for a debugging tool/method that I can use to discover what the problem is when [PocketSphinx.js](https://syl22-00.github.io/pocketsphinx.js/) does not recognize a custom word I have defined.  Specifically, I would like to be able to see what phonemes that [PocketSphinx.js](https://syl22-00.github.io/pocketsphinx.js/) is actually hearing when a word is not recognized.

Details:
I am working on developing a voice interface for a website.  I need to use a custom keyword, and I am working with [PocketSphinx.js](https://syl22-00.github.io/pocketsphinx.js/).  The custom keyword I've chosen is "Berk-o-bot" with a [CMU pronunciation](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict) of "B ER K OW B AA T".  I've had very low success getting this phrase to recognize.  (Recognizes only about a quarter of the time I slowly and deliberately say the word, never if I speak at normal speed.) NOTE:
If I split the word into smaller chunks (Berk [B ER K], Berk-O [B ER K OW], O-bot [OW B AA T] or bot [B AA T]), the smaller chunks recognize easily.

Thoughts from failed attempts:

- My suspicion is that the recognizer has difficulty since the first and thirds syllables are accented, but not the 2nd.  I have tried using adding [Arpabet Stress Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARPABET) to the pronunciation [B ER1 K OW0 B AA2 T] but pocketsphinx.js threw errors when I would try to add the word to the dictionary.
- I've also tried adding multiple pronunciations to the dictionary like BERK-O-BOT(2) [B ER K AO B AA T], BERK-O-BOT(3) [B ER K AH B AA T], BERK-O-BOT(4) [B ER K EH B AA T], BERK-O-BOT(5) [B ER K UH B AA T] but did not see any improvement in recognition.
- I am new to pocketsphinx.js, so the above two methods might work, but I might be implementing them incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it working on desktop with pocketsphinx_continuous and pre-recorded audio files first. Once it works you can try in a web browser with the same configuration and models.

You can share audio files and the configuration/models if it still doesn't work to get more detailed help.

Comment: can honkling be used for speech-to-text? or any other library like that except Google's text-to-speach engine?

Comment: I really appreciate the pointer to newer projects.  My ultimate goal is to find the most sensible way to make my voice engine recognize a bit over 5,300 words where over 300 of them are proper nouns (Company names, City Names, etc.), and preferably able to do continuous recognition so that it can be activated by a keyword ("Berk-o-bot")  I've been looking at honkling, but haven't found the documentation on how to add custom words.  Is this something honkling can do?

Comment: No, honkling is just for activation keyword. The rest has to be handled by speech API.